# Coversion of IST date format to Oracle sysdate format

Tags: datetime, oracle11g, localization, date-format

How can I to convert from Indian standard time format to oracle date format.

Eg:

```
Mon May 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

required format

```
23-May-16
```

Comment: Dates do not have formats, they are binary values. IST refers to timezones, not formats. Oracle *has* date types so there is no need to store strings instead of dates. Either you've stored strings in the database instead of dates (that's a bug), or you want to format a date value to a specific format for display - something best done on the client side? If you have to do this on the server, you should check Oracle's string formatting functions like `to_char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parses the input string and returns a date value to you:

```
select cast(to_timestamp_tz('Mon May 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530', 'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS "GMT"TZHTZM') as date) as converted_to_date_value
from dual;
```

This parses the input string to a "timestamp with time zone" value and formats the value back to a string in your desired format:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('Mon May 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530', 'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS "GMT"TZHTZM'), 'DD-Mon-RR') as converted_to_your_format
from dual;
```

Enjoy!

**Footnote:** Please note that there's no such thing as "oracle date format" which you refer to. Oracle has its `date` data type, which can have many many many different display intepretations depending on your client as well as server locale settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.